Ubuntu 24.04 Virtual Machine stuck on Grub terminal after power loss
There are many posts regarding this error state, but I could not find one that matches my specific circumstances.
I have an Ubuntu 24.04 virtual machine running in Hyper V on a Windows Server 2022 host. The virtual machine configuration files and VHD are stored on an encrypted partition, which has to be manually decrypted and mounted, after Windows is loaded. I installed Ubuntu from the regular bootable ISO, and used all the default options: no special partitioning, not encrypted,
My Windows host machine suffered an unexpected power loss while the encrypted partition was mounted, and the Ubuntu VM was running. The computer is on a UPS and Windows shut down gracefully, but it closed the software which has the encrypted partition mounted, so essentially the VM had its config files and VHD unexpectedly yanked.
Now I mount my encrypted partition and the VM config files and VHDX file are all present, but the VM will not boot. It is stuck at the Grub terminal: "GRUB version 2.12 - Minimal BASH-like editing is supported"
If I type exit it fails to boot. I tried using ls command to find (hd0,1)/boot/grub or (hd0,1)/grub, but I'm not seeing what I would expect, from the posts on other questions in this forum.
I have 2 HD partitions visible, (hd0,gpt1)/ and (hd0,gpt2)/. On gpt2 there is the normal Ubuntu file system, with dev, etc, home, root, var, and everything one would expect. There is a (hd0,gpt2)/boot directory there as well, but it is completely empty.
On gpt1, there is an efi/boot/ directory, containing three things : bootx64.efi, fbx64.efi, and mmx64.efi
I have run the Boot-Repair utility and generated a report, but I am not experienced enough to know if the output provides a definitive answer to the problem. Here is the output:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VXCxTbb6Ph/
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/sda2: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: hyperv_fb from 
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: Hyper-V UEFI Release v4.1(4.1) from Microsoft Corporation
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0004,0000,0001
Boot0000* EFI Network   AcpiEx(VMBus,,)/VenHw(9b17e5a2-0891-42dd-b653-80b5c22809ba,635161f83edfc546913ff2d2f965ed0edf1dec843a46494397b30de190024a60)/MAC(000000000000,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)
Boot0001* EFI SCSI Device   AcpiEx(VMBus,,)/VenHw(9b17e5a2-0891-42dd-b653-80b5c22809ba,d96361baa104294db60572e2ffb1dc7f613cb167ca94f74cb428bd01f7aee3f4)/SCSI(0,0)
Boot0002* EFI SCSI Device   AcpiEx(VMBus,,)/VenHw(9b17e5a2-0891-42dd-b653-80b5c22809ba,d96361baa104294db60572e2ffb1dc7f613cb167ca94f74cb428bd01f7aee3f4)/SCSI(0,1)
Boot0003* FrontPage MemoryMapped(11,0x100000,0x5dffff)/FvFile(4042708a-0f2d-4823-ac60-0d77b3111889)
Boot0004* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,a35a8755-b61f-4b57-b6e2-f54ea8711ad0,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)

39bc76ff6662f4fbe9aa116e4c997b41   sda1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
4ba5a5aad43c197e9fb58b76b404d287   sda1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
66f69798ad23240e43b7ba0044a914c4   sda1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4ba5a5aad43c197e9fb58b76b404d287   sda1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   sda1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   sda1/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda2    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 900 GiB, 966367641600 bytes, 1887436800 sectors
Disk identifier: 10A2C798-6944-410F-AF0E-ED58C3E0D1CF
       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sda1     2048    2203647    2201600     1G EFI System
sda2  2203648 1887434751 1885231104 898.9G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:966GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:Msft Virtual Disk:;
1:1049kB:1128MB:1127MB:fat32::boot, esp;
2:1128MB:966GB:965GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                  PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                              
├─sda1 vfat     AAEE-CC53                            a35a8755-b61f-4b57-b6e2-f54ea8711ad0                        
└─sda2 ext4     f76f1ded-c9c1-49e4-8d7e-abb902d28bf7 8b69b5db-1323-4cb0-bc0e-323d39d4829f                        

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                           Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                     1G   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
efivarfs                    128M   0% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1                 vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid f76f1ded-c9c1-49e4-8d7e-abb902d28bf7 root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.

